# Python/Pandas/Timeseries : How to define Work Start Time /Work End time and extract the working hour?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I imported below packages from jupyter notebook to extract working hour.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as d
import time
df = pd.read_excel(rawdata)
```

The raw data looks like below which is an Excel column

```
╔═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗  
║ Start Date Time     ║  End Date Time      ║  
╠═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣  
║ 2020-02-18 16:00:00 ║ 2020-02-08 21:00:00 ║  
║ 2020-02-19 07:00:00 ║ 2020-02-19 12:00:00 ║  
║ 2020-02-20 12:00:00 ║ 2020-02-21 14:00:00 ║  
╚═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

So I changed the types..

- Start Date to consider Week Day(On duty) / Weekend(Off duty) / National Holiday(Off duty)
- Start Day
- Start Time to extract working hour / over time
- Same for End Date as well

  ```
  df['Start Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date and Time'])
  df['start_date'] = df['Start Date and Time'].dt.date
  df['start_day'] = df['Start Date and Time'].dt.weekday_name
  df['start_time'] = df['Start Date and Time'].dt.time
  ```

I can simply subtract df['End Date and Time'] - df['Start Date and Time'] for net duration, but my question how to apply a time frame to separate official working hour and over time.

Official Working Hour : 09AM - 06PM

My plan is to (1) simply subtract End - Start Time  (2) See if it happened during 09AM ~ 06PM   (3) Calculate (1)-(2)=Over Time

Seeking your advice for (2) because I have never worked with the time series data, and time series is really confusing..
Appreciate your advice !!

Comment: Can you share the code in which you have tried to extract the data ?

Comment: If it is a excel sheet then you might want to look into xlrd python package

Comment: @RishabhHardas
I added the code !!

Comment: As you said you can get the time in office. Then consider your office timing is 8am to 5pm, then the time spent in office before 8 am and after 5pm can be easily calculate. I think the question is more about the mathematics to calculate the time and not one related to programming